# Can’t login after FF browser update

Tags: users

My Firefox has just updated to version 17.1. When I try and login I get this message:

> Access denied
>   You are not authorized to access this page.

The URL does however recognize my account as it contains /users/myusername

I can log in fine in older versions of Firefox, and Internet Explorer. I however get the same problem in Safari version 4 Public Beta (528.16).

Does anyone know a fix for this? I have tried rebuilding permissions but it didn't help.

I am running Drupal 6.

Comment: http://bit.ly/Kc8M2e or http://bit.ly/mBoI7 may help

Comment: Given that the question clearly states that the problem is browser related and not Drupal, I vote off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar situation was encountered by [a user who reported that clearing his browser cookies solved the problem](https://code.google.com/p/myphpips/issues/detail?id=5).

Comment: Hi, thank you Beth. Turns out Safari and the lastest version of FF have "accept cookies" set to never by default. I changed it to always and can now login.